# Modifying Embedded Chart Axes in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-workspace

I try to modify embedded chart vertical axes  minimal / maximal value range in gsuite spreadsheet - but did not found options how to do this anywhere... just in this way:

```
function modifyAxes() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('mySheet'); 
var chart = sh.getCharts()[0];
chart = chart.modify()
// set vAxis minimal range or so..
.build();
sh.update
```

Did you get any hint?